# Defintion of proper homotopy

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

The definition of proper homotopy $H: [0,1]\times X\rightarrow X$ requires that $H(t,x)$ is proper as a full map (from product $[0,1]\times X$ to $X$).

I feel that it is not equivalent to that $H(t,\cdot): X\rightarrow X$ is proper for each fixed $t\in [0,1]$ (on the other hand, if $X$ is compact, both cases are true).

Do you know any counterexample, when for each fixed $t$, $H_t(x) = H(t,x)$ is proper but the full map is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb R.$ The homotopy will be from the identity map to itself, so $H(0,x)=H(1,x)=x$ for all $x.$ For each integer $n\geq 1,$ during the time period $[1/(n+1),1/n],$ the point $n\in X$ is taken to $0$ and back, and points outside $[n-1,n+1]$ are not affected ($H(t,x)=x$ for $x\not\in[n-1,n+1]$ and $t\in[1/(n+1),1/n]$). Then $H^{-1}(\{0\})$ is unbounded, but $H_t^{-1}(\{0\})$ is bounded for each $t.$

Comment: I don't understand what is "taken to 0 and back"; what happens to the points inside (n-1,n+1)\{n}?; the map H(t,x) looks discontinuous, no?

Comment: @FedorGoncharov: I just mean $H(t,n)=0$ for some $t\in[1/(n+1),1/n],$ and $H(t,x)=x$ on the boundary of $[1/(n+1),1/n]\times [n-1,n+1].$ It should be straightforward to see there are such maps that are continuous at least on $[1/(n+1),1/n]\times [n-1,n+1]$ e.g. piecewise linear. At what points do you think $H$ would be discontinuous?

Comment: In the sup-norm: $\sup_x |H_{t_n}(x) - H_0(x)| \geq |H_{t_n}(n) - H_0(n)| = n$, so the sequence $H_{t_n}$ is not close to identity, however $t_n \rightarrow 0$. Maybe I'm a bit wrong, but I always thought that homotopy is continuous with respect to the sup-norm (canonically it should be open-compact topology, but I guess that sup-norm induces this topology).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking incorrectly, sup-norm is not a compact open topology if the source space is not compact, it is stronger. And open-compact topology in this case is the inductive limit, which corresponds to your example, so you are correct! Thanks a lot, I was thinking of bad definition!