Extending isotopy to the one-point compactificaton of $\mathbb{R}^n$
Exercise 12.6 in Adams and Franzosa's "Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied" suggests proving that if two knots are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then they are equivalent in $S^3$ (which can be seen as a one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^3$). Naturally, I can't see any other way except to prove their ambient isotopy $F$ witnessing their equivalence in $\mathbb{R}^3$ extends to some $\hat{F}$ in $S^3$.
The extension (putting $\hat{F}(\infty, t) = \infty$ and agreeing with $F$ everywhere else) and most of its properties are obvious, except continuity, which I struggle to prove. I've found this question (which talks about manifolds that I don't know about yet but can probably gloss that over) and even this paper that prove very relevant things (always fun when your textbook exercise is proven in a paper, right?), but they do so in a more general setting of some locally compact Hausdorff space instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which has much more structure. For instance, the set $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus C$ for $C$ compact has a very nice geometric intuition that just asks for being used in some way in the proof. And, given the overall style of the book, I doubt the authors expect the student to come up with something like in the links above.
So I am wondering, can this be proven for $\mathbb{R}^n$ specifically in a more direct, specialized way?

What the ambient isotopy is doing outside of a ball containing the knots doesn't matter as far as the definition of knot equivalence goes. So instead of proving that an arbitrary ambient isotopy $F$ extends continuously (I don't know whether this is true or not) you can prove that two knots are ambient isotopic iff they're ambient isotopic by an isotopy which is the identity outside of some ball. That seems approachable; if this isn't straightforward to prove then it's not clear that ambient isotopy is the "meaningful" definition of knot equivalence anyway.

It seems intuitive, but I'm not sure how to prove it rigorously. The isotopy on the left-hand side of the "iff" might deform the space outside any ball, and it's not obvious how to undo that just outside the ball containing the knots.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4878714/when-can-a-homotopy-lift-to-its-compactification/4880468#4880468

@MoisheKohan I've seen that and it's very valuable! But I'm curious if it can be specialized to the more specific situation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or even just $\mathbb{R}^3$) instead of arbitrary locally compact Hausdorff space.

Ok, I think I got this. The crucial point of my proof hinges on $F^{-1}(C)$ being compact for $C$ compact, and I think now it's fairly obvious why it holds for $F$ an isotopy. I'll double-check my proof tomorrow with fresh eyes and write up an answer.

Theorem 2.1 in the paper by Crowell that you linked, which proves exactly what you ask about in the general case of a locally compact Hausdorff space, is pretty straightforward, reasonably elegant, and has full details. Besides writing a proof that skimps on some of those details, or using the degree method in the linked answer by @MoisheKohan, I doubt that there is a proof for the special case of $\mathbb R^n$ that is much different that the general case.
